# Actionbarsherlock internal error

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have problem with actionbarsherlok in my androia app.( I using ScrollingTabContainerView to create tabs. And when I select current tab second time, I have this error

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$1.run(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:247)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is it? How I can correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Activate the log of ABS :

In the ImageLoaderConfiguration builder :

```
.enableLogging()
```

then in the callbacks onLoadingStarted, onLoadingFailed, onLoadingComplete, do some log just in case.

for example :

```
@Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                    String message = null;
                    switch (failReason.getType()) {
                        case IO_ERROR:
                            message = "Input/Output error";
                            break;
                        case DECODING_ERROR:
                            message = "Image can't be decoded";
                            break;
                        case NETWORK_DENIED:
                            message = "Downloads are denied";
                            break;
                        case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                            message = "Out Of Memory error";
                            break;
                        case UNKNOWN:
                            message = "Unknown error";
                            break;
                    }
                    Log.e("ImageLoader", "ERROR : " + message);
                }
```

Now execute your application and filter you logs wih ImageLoader and see if there is any warning/error